# How can I profile my Laravel app on GAE to help performance?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, laravel-4

I have a app running on GAE and its really slow. For a basic response it takes about 900ms. I'm using memcache for sessions and not hitting the database. The meta/services.json requires write access and has to be placed on cloud storage. How can I profile my app to see why its running slow?

I've seen a preview for googles app debugger but its not available yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the services.json file was missing because of the default laravel git config. It doesn't need to be writable but was just be excluded from git. Once it was included responses were 500+ms faster. I had to specifically change the storage path for meta to not be using cloud storage.